# How did tetrachords become whole and half steps?

Tags: theory, chords, scales, intervals, tetrachords

How did the ancient Greek concept of tetrachords evolve into the whole- and half-step model familiar today?

Comment: Do you mean the enharmonic, diatonic and chromatic tetrachord described by Aristoxenos? Or Pythagoras' idea of stacking pure fifths on each other to deduce the 'white keys'-diatonic scales, consisting of two tetrachords per octave

Comment: @Michel Wait, aren’t they part of the same history. I.e., Pythagoras had his discoveries and Aristoxenus built on those later?

Comment: yes but Aristoxenos talked more about the 'microtuning', with the enharmonic being the most complex tetrachord, containing dieses. And I think Pythagoras did non care about the microtuning, he used the 'bare' tuning which later was named after him (Pythagorean tuning)

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(music)#Enharmonic

Comment: Throughout history, scales kept getting larger in range (ie. notes were added).
Today, each diatonic scale can be thought of as consisting of 2 tetrachords, but the term simply denotes 4 consecutive notes, while I think in ancient Greece, they thought of them as modes. If you think of scales in terms of tetrachords, you can quickly classify them into minor-major, major-minor, minor-harmonic, major-harmonic, minor-melodic, major-melodic, etc.